# Error Access denied when trying to get mailfolders using Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to rech the endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{emailaddress}/mailFolders('InBox') but am receiving
```

Error Access Denied response.

I have granted both Mail.Read.Shared and Mail.ReadWrite.Shared on delegated permission.

The scenario I have is that in Azure AD there are a number of users , Manager@acme.com  and Tests@acme.com , so they exist under the same tennant /organization.

I have an app whereby I login as Manager@acme.com as the current user. I the create a connection to the App using client id , secret etc and receive an Auth toke n to use in my api calls.

but when i try to call

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/Tests@acme.com/mailFolders('InBox') with that token I
```

get the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
  }
```

}

Do i ned to grant both Mail.Read.Shared and Mail.ReadWrite.Shared  on Application level ?
Or do i need to create a shared folder in Outlook ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `Mail.Read.Shared` or `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared` exist as assignable application permissions.

The only permission your App Registration should need is `Mail.Read`, unless you're intending on the using Graph to delete / send emails etc.

You will likely also need an ApplicationAccessPolicy.  You can either create one in the Exchange Online Admin Center, or through PowerShell.  I recommend you create a mail enabled security group for all addresses which you need to access and grant restricted access to your app through that policy.

I prefer PowerShell, so in that case you would need the ExchangePowerShell module, and connect to Exchange Online.  You'll need some Exchange admin role to be able to do this.

So, let's assume you've created a mail enabled security group called GraphAccessibleUsers@acme.com.  You can set the property to hide this from the GAL so users can't see it.

You would then create a policy as follows:

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AccessRight RestrictAccess -AppId "<Your-App-Registration-Id" -PolicyScopeGroupId GraphAccessibleUsers@acme.com -Description "Allow App access to users in GraphAccessibleUsers@acme.com"
```

The `-PolicyScopeId` parameter will accept:

1. Name
2. Distinguished name (DN)
3. Display name
4. Email address
5. GUID

If you only have a few addresses, you may opt to create an individual ApplicationAccessPolicy for each email address.

**Finally**, I don't think your Graph API URI is correct.

If you want to access the Inbox of Tests@acme.com, then try this instead:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/Tests@acme.com/mailFolders/Inbox`

Please refer to [mailFolder Resource Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0) here.

Comment: I havent taken the approach of creating an ApplicationAccessPolicy yet. I thought i would try the following. I created a shared mail box with email shared@acme.com. I then gave access to that mailbox for my email User1@acme.com. When i relaunched Outlook I could successfully see the new email and its folders.  I have Authorized and receive a token, so I would have thought if i called https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/Tests@acme.com/mailFolders I would have received the mailfolders for that email ie shared@acme.com ?

Comment: If you use Microsoft Graph Explorer then yes.  But why?  Because Graph Explorer asks you to sign in and retrieves an OAuth token for your account to be able to make the correct calls.  The HTTP request must have the token in the header or access will be denied.  You can find more information on using the OAuth endpoint to retrieve a token here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-token, but you must note it still relies on app registration and everything I said above.  Mailbox sharing is internal to Exchange.  Graph is not the same.